# How to get two lists into one list as two elements?

Tags: ocaml

I want to put two lists into one list but not using append. It will get two lists mixed. I want these two lists as two elements in the new list. The new list only have two elements---the first list and the second list.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
let list2 a b = [ a; b ]
```

This works for any two values `a`, `b`, of the same type. They can be lists or anything else:

```
$ ocaml
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# let list2 a b = [a; b];;
val list2 : 'a -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>
# list2 [1;2] [3;4];;
- : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
# list2 "yes" "no";;
- : string list = ["yes"; "no"]
#
```

(If your two lists aren't the same type it's not possible to put them into a list. OCaml lists are homogeneous--all elements have the same type.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **function** to do so :

Using ***append()*** directly will not give the desired result.See the code snippet for a list containing multiple lists.
    
     `def foo(list1,list2):
        new_list =[]
        for i in range(0,len(list1)):
            new_list.append(list1[i])
        for j in range(0,len(list2)):
            new_list.append(list2[j])
        return new_list`

Comment: (OP is asking for an OCaml solution.)